# Execute shell script through prometheus alert manger

Tags: linux, shell, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Please let me know if I can execute a shell script on the same server as Prometheus/alertmanager on an alert trigger?
If so, help me with the configurations.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Prometheus-am-executor](https://github.com/imgix/prometheus-am-executor) to run any shell or even python script too.

Here is sample.yml file

```yaml
listen_address: ":8094" # Where alertmanager sending alerts
# Display more output
verbose: true
commands:
  - cmd: python3
    args: ["script.py"] # Script which you want to execute
```

Answer (score 1):

A maintained alternative is https://github.com/adnanh/webhook which allows you to do install local webhooks with scripts attached.

Example config:

```
- id: redeploy-webhook
  execute-command: "/var/scripts/redeploy.sh"
  command-working-directory: "/var/webhook"
```

Default port of the webhook process is 9000, so the following URL would execute the redeploy.sh script from above config example.

```
http://yourserver:9000/hooks/redeploy-webhook
```

Which can be then used in your alertmanager config:

```
receivers:
- name: 'general'
  webhook_config:
  - url: http://yourserver:9000/hooks/redeploy-webhook
```